# Better alternative for "data-only" Objective-C objects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns, nsdictionary, cocoa-design-patterns

I run into design choices like this often and struggle a bit; I'm looking for some other perspectives.

I often want to keep lists of, or pass around chunks of state that are basically just sets of values. The values tend to be primitive types: floats, NSTimeIntervals, CGPoints, etc.

My first inclination is often to create C structures for these sets of properties, e.g.

```
typedef struct _STATE {
    float foo;
    NSTimeInterval elapsed;
    CGPoint point;
} STATE;
```

etc.

But C structures don't play nicely with the native Cocoa collection classes (`NSArray`, `NSSet`, `NSDictionary`), and using overmany of them to track lots of state feels like it runs against the grain of rest of my Cocoa-friendly code-- I end up having and directly managing arrays of structs, and passing struct pointers around in messages, etc.

On the other hand, since raw performance isn't necessarily critical, I could encode these values into a NSDictionary, wrapping them all in `NSValue` or `NSNumber`, but the resulting syntax is hardly terse, and a little fragile, requiring type and name correctness at runtime for both the insert and the lookup:

```
[stateDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:foo] forKey:@"bar"];
... 
float something = [[stateDict objectForKey:@"bar"] floatValue];
```

and some types, like NSTimeInterval, are only able to be used with some (arguable) hackery (typecast to double in that case).

Finally, I could create data-only container objects, with private member data and only getters/setters. (These would be called "beans" in Java.) These are more terse to access than dictionaries, more Cocoa than structs, but feel like overkill to me, especially if I only need them as "inner classes" that are used for state management internal to a single object type.

How do you, great Cocoa programming public, do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depending on the situation, I run either with using NSDictionary classes for arbitrary data, or I create container classes (the @property/synthesize tags in Objective C make this really easy).  By using ObjC for the header file:

```
@interface StateObject : NSObject {
    NSNumber *foo;
    NSTimeInterval *elapsed;
    CGPoint point;
}

@property (retain) NSNumber *foo;
@property (retain) NSTimeInterval *elapsed;
@property (copy)   CGPoint point;

@end
```

One can then use `@synthesize <variable>` in the .m file to automatically create the setters/getters.  Then, while anonymous NSNumbers are still ornery, you can do:

```
myStateObject.foo = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:7.0];
```

This should take most of the pain away, and let you use the Cocoa collection classes to better shuffle data around.

Comment: +1. Creating model classes is almost always the way to go unless you have some very performance-critical code where the overhead of using objects will cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for this Matt. In this scenario, you don't even need to wrap floats with NSNumber-- one can use the @property syntax to access primitive types. (Same goes of course for NSTimeInterval, which happens to be a typedef'd primitive float.)

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily endorsing this approach as "best", but there is a middle ground between your proposals: create C structs to hold the information, and then wrap the structs in `NSValue` objects when you need to put them into Cocoa data structures. You can see UIKit do this in some cases with structs like `CGPoint` in notifications (and I'm sure that AppKit does, as well).

See "Using Values" in [*Number and Value Programming Topics for Cocoa*](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000174) for more on that.